# PHP correct way to share classes db connect and vars config with other classes

Tags: php

I have some classes that must connect to the db and take of shared variables, so I would like to ask you some information about it.

For db I tried to create a class Singletone.

```
class Database  
{  
   /**
    * @const Mysqli parameters 
    */
    const HOST = "xxxxx";  
    const USER = "xxxxx";  
    const PASS = "xxxxx";  
    const DB   = "xxxxx";  

   /**
    * @var $instance The class instance
    */
    private static $instance; 

   /**
    * Class constructor
    * block directly instantiating
    */  
    private function __construct() {} 

   /**
    * Class clone
    * block cloning of the object
    */  
    private function __clone() {} 

   /**
    * Initialize Mysqli
    * create the instance if it does not exist
    * @return void 
    */  
    public static function init()  
    {  
         if(!isset(self::$instance))  
         {  
               self::$instance = new Mysqli(self::HOST, self::USER, self::PASS, self::DB);  

              if(self::$instance->connect_error)  
              {  
                     throw new Exception('MySQL connection failed: ' . self::$instance->connect_error);  
              }  
          }  
          return self::$instance;  
    }  
 }
```

In the other classes call the class Singletone in this way

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var $db init database class
     */
     private $db;

    /**
     * Class constructor 
     */
     public function __construct() 
     {
           $this->db = Database::init();
     }

    /**
     * Simple mysql select
     */
     public function simpleSQL() 
     {
         $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
            while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                  echo $r['email'] . "<br />";
            }
     }
 }
```

- Is this the correct approach?
- My code is correct?

Now as regards the variables (which are taken by a db) I thought to do create a new class

```
class Config
{
   /**
    * @var $db init database class
    */
    private $db;

   /**
    * @var $public_ip
    * @type string
    */
    public $public_ip;

   /**
    * @var $public_port
    * @type string
    */
    public $public_port;

   /**
    * @var $manage_ip
    * @type string
    */
    public $manage_ip;

   /**
    * @var $manage_port
    * @type string
    */
    public $manage_port;

   /**
    * Class constructor 
    */
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->db = Database::init();
        $this->setVars();
    }

   /**
    * Set variables "global"
    * @return @void
    */
    public function setVars() 
    {
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = 1");
         while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
              $this->public_ip  = $r['public_ip'];
              $this->public_port  = $r['public_port'];
              $this->manage_ip  = $r['manage_ip'];
              $this->manage_port    = $r['manage_port'];
        }
   }
}
```

and then initialize it in the other classes in this way

```
class Users
{
private $db;
private $cnf;

/**
 * Class constructor 
 */
 public function __construct() 
 {
     $this->db = Database::init();
     $this->cnf = new Config();
 }

/**
 * Simple mysql select
 */
 public function simpleSQL() 
 {
     $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
         while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
         {
             echo $r['email'] . "<br />";
         }
 }

/**
 * Get vars
 */
 public function getVars() 
 {
     echo $this->cnf->public_ip . "<br />";
     echo $this->cnf->public_port . "<br />";
     echo $this->cnf->manage_ip . "<br />";
     echo $this->cnf->manage_port . "<br />";
 }
}

class foo
{

 private $db;
 private $cnf;

 /**
  * Class constructor 
  */
 public function __construct() 
 {
     $this->db = Database::init();
     $this->cnf = new Config();
 }

/**
 * Get vars
 */
 public function getVars() 
 {
     echo $this->cnf->public_ip . "<br />";
     echo $this->cnf->public_port . "<br />";
     echo $this->cnf->manage_ip . "<br />";
     echo $this->cnf->manage_port . "<br />";
 }
}
```

- is this the right way to do this?
- What would be the correct approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to create one Class that does the actual DB connection and executes queries. This Connector class is then shared between all of your classes with data access.

This cass should NOT be a static or singleton class. Just instantiate it during application start and give it to all classes that need it. Maybe inside the constructor, or even better with a dedicated setter.

```
$Connector = new Connector("user", "pass", "other stuff from config");

$Users = new Users($Connector);
$Users->doStuff();

class Users
{
    private $connector;

    public function __construct($connector) 
    {
        $this->connector = $connector
    }

    public function doStuff(){
        $result = $this->connector->query("SELECT STUFF");
    }
}
```

With this method, you could allways just change or replace your connector class to some other DB without changin anything in your apps. Implement Interfaces and some Dependency Injection (Strategy Pattern?) for Bonus points.

Comment: Thanks, even if I had read that the singleton pattern was the right way to connect to the db.

Comment: Singleton pattern is allways a bad idea. It makes testing and extending your application very hard. See comment from deceze above.

Comment: For cleaning of my project,can I keep 2 separate classes (database and config) and then initialize them in the constructor of the other classes or I would have a recursive connection to the db ? thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi read deceze's blogpost (I just stumbled upon it and that's the best DI article I've ever read). He is covering exactely what you are asking for. You don't create new instance inside a class, you pass instances instead.