# Share a parameters class with other classes

Tags: php

I would like to share the parameters taken from a table in a db.
To take these parameters, I created a class made ​​for this.
this is my scenario to share the parameters contained in a db between the various classes. is the correct approach to do this?

```
class Database 
{
    $private mys; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mys = new mysqli(....); 
    }
}

class params
{ 
    $private db;
    $public var1;
    $public var2;

    public function __construct()
    {
          $this->db = new Database();
    } 

    public function getParams()
    {
        $result = $this->db->mys->query ("SELECT * FROM params");

           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
           {
                $this->var1 = $row['var1'];
                $this->var2 = $row['var2'];
           }    
    }

}

class foo
{
    private $db;
    private $ps;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
        $this->ps = new Params;

    }

    public function viewParams()
    {
          echo $this->ps->var1;
          echo $this->ps->var2;
    }

 }
```

Comment: No, class members declared 'private' are private to that class and are invisible from outside, e.g.: $this->db->mys and $this->ps->var1

Comment: This question seems to be common today. Check this one and especially the Blog in the first comment! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734150

Comment: The db objects are not only relative to their class scope, you've made them private, so no, they can't share. Create a db class they can all use. If they all need same data, run that query in separate class so all can call that shared query statically.

Comment: I suggest you to not share values from a database. You can create a file that contains a php array (for example), based on that records. I cannot imagine how many times you do same query to get same values.

Comment: I edit my code (public var replaced private var). But I would like to know if my approach is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access the private fields from other classes declare public 'getter' methods like:

```
public getVal1() {
 return $this->val1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my modest opinion, there are various ways to share a parameters class with other classes. And they depends on how your system currently is and how it'll grow.

From what I learnt, a correct ways to pass dependencies to your classes is to inject they to the constructor, ex instead of:

```
class foo
{
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
```

I would prefer to instanciate `$db` first:

```
$db = new Database();
```

and then

```
class foo
{
    ...
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
```

This way your classes are loosely coupled and you can afford Unit Testing easily one day, working with interfaces and not concrete implementations, etc...please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

**As a personal suggest** I'll try to design the params class as an entity, mapped as a Db table object:

```
//entityParams.php
class EntityParams
{
    private $id; //column name
    private $columnA;
    private $columnB; 

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setColumnA($columnA)
    {
        $this->columnA = $columnA;
    }
    ...
```

}

then use a `Database` class as a simple connector class (just to [promotes single-responsibility and separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))):

```
//Database.php
class Database
{
    private $dbh = NULL;

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->dbh = new Mysqli(...);
    }

    public function getConnection()
    {
        if(is_null($this->dbh))
        {
            $this->connect();
        }

        return $this->dbh;
    }
}
```

and use a DatabaseManager instead, to let it do all dirty works.Something like:

```
//DatabaseManager.php
class DatabaseManager
{
    private $db;
    private $entities = array();
    private $currentEntity;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function fromEntity($entityName)
    {
        $entityClass = "Entity".ucfirst($entityName);

        if(!isset($this->entities[$entityClass]))
        {
            $this->entities[$entityClass] = $entityName;
        }

        $this->currentEntity = $entityClass;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        $results = $this->db->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM {$this->entities[$this->currentEntity]}");

        $entities = array();

        foreach ($results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $key => $item) 
        {
            $e = new $this->currentEntity;
            $e->setId($item['id']);
            $e->setColumnA($item['columnA']);
            $e->setColumnB($item['columnB']); 

            $entities[] = $e;
        }

       return $entities;
   }
```

Finally your Foo class (and everyone else) just has a simple dependency with the DatabaseManager (which could evolve as a RespositoryManager):

```
//Foo.php
class Foo
{
    public $dbm;

    public function __construct(DatabaseManager $dbm)
    {
        $this->dbm = $dbm;
    }

    public function viewParams()
    {
        return $this->dbm->fromEntity("params")->getAll();
    }

    public function viewParam($id)
    {
        return $this->dbm->fromEntity("params")->find(2);
    }
}    

//client.php
/* Here you can instantiate the classes and pass they through constructor or investigate on how to create and use a Dependency Injection Container */
$db = new Database();
$dbm = new DatabaseManager($db);

$foo = new Foo($dbm);

var_dump($foo->viewParams());
var_dump($foo->viewParam(1));
```

I just wrote simple basic ideas that could be worth to play around it and improve it.